# How to limit the number of call record in CDR file

Tags: asterisk, cdr

My call records are getting store in /var/log/asterisk/cdr-csv/Master.csv file. i want to limit the number of call to be stored ni this file, after that it should start form the beginning,
so for this what could be procedure

Answer (score 1):

You can't limit number of records by asterisk

But you easy can rotate files by using logrotate linux utility.

For that you should create file /etc/logrotate.d/asterisk_cdr

```
/var/log/asterisk/cdr-csv/*csv {
missingok
rotate 5
size 2000k
create 0640 asterisk asterisk
}
```

For more info see documentation for logrotated